# Store Data in memory to access later on

Tags: c++, file, winapi, directory

New to C++.  I have a code that spins thru directories to look for a specific file (123.txt) and lists the result in a textbox.  What i need to do is store these result in memory so i can access it later. An array maybe? I'm not exactly sure how that's done.

Here's the code to execute it:

```
outfile1.open("pxutil1.log");

    DWORD dwSize = MAX_PATH;
    char szLogicalDrives[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD dwResult = GetLogicalDriveStrings(dwSize, szLogicalDrives);
    if (dwResult == 0)
    {
        // error handling...
    }
    else if (dwResult > MAX_PATH)
    {
        // not enough buffer space...
    }
    else
    {
        for (char* szSingleDrive = szLogicalDrives; *szSingleDrive != 0; szSingleDrive += (lstrlenA(szSingleDrive) + 1))
        {
            if (GetDriveTypeA(szSingleDrive) == DRIVE_FIXED)
                FindFile(szSingleDrive);
        }
    }
```

Here's the code to search for 123.txt and list the restult in a logfile.

```
std::string dir = directory;
    if ((!dir.empty()) && (dir.back() != '\\') && (dir.back() != '/'))
        dir += '\\';

    WIN32_FIND_DATAA file;
    HANDLE search_handle = FindFirstFileA((dir + "*").c_str(), &file);
    if (search_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
        {
            // error handling...
            //::MessageBox(NULL, "File not found", "", MB_OK);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            if (file.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
                if ((lstrcmpA(file.cFileName, ".") != 0) && (lstrcmpA(file.cFileName, "..") != 0))
                {
                    //FindFile(dir + file.cFileName);
                    if (!ExcludeDir(dir + file.cFileName))
                    {
                        FindFile(dir + file.cFileName);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (lstrcmpA(file.cFileName, "123.txt") == 0)
                {                   
                    outfile1 << dir.c_str() << endl; //write to log file                
                }
            }
        } while (FindNextFileA(search_handle, &file));

        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
        {
            ::MessageBox(NULL, "No more files", "", MB_OK);
        }

        FindClose(search_handle);
    }
```

I thought maybe i could add this to the code, but it doesn't work

```
string listOfDir[20]

std::string(dir) >> listOfDir;
```

Comment: check this https://openclassrooms.com/fr/courses/1894236-programmez-avec-le-langage-c/1896398-lisez-et-modifiez-des-fichiers

Comment: @JaziriRami English version??

Comment: Try using `std::vector<string> listOfDir;`.  Then search the internet for `c++ output iterator` or use a loop to print each slot of the vector.

Comment: This boils down to a handful of lines of code, provided you use [std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator).

Answer (score 0):

The standard C++ language does not have overloads of `operator>>` to input arrays.
The following does not work:

```
std::cin >> listOfDir;
```

The C++ language does not have any functions to split a string.
The following does not work:

```
std::string(dir) >> listOfDir;
```

The compiler can't find any overload of `operator>>` that takes a `std::string` parameter and an array parameter.  The statement would be equivalent of:

```
operator>>(std::string, std::string[]);
```

In summary, you'll need to write the code yourself to parse or split a string; or you can search the internet for a string library.

If you use `std::vector`, this code may be more useful:

```
std::vector<std::string> listOfDir;  
//...
listOfDir.push_back(dir);
```

The above code fragment appends a copy of `dir` to the vector `listOfDir`.